# Equivalente à "Show you around" em português

Tags: expressões, tradução

Qual seria o equivalente para "show you around" em português? "Mostrar os arredores", "mostrar por ai" não soam muito natural.

> If you come to Brazil, I can show you around.

Como poderia traduzir isso?

Comment: If you come to Bahia, I can show you around.  You can't show a person around [a country]. No one says that. You show someone around a specific place or area in a country. Então, mostra o lugar não funciona. Mostra a cidade, sim.

Comment: to show someone around [a place] means to accompany them while they visit it.

Comment: @Lambie thank you for the insight, I didn’t know you “cannot” show someone around a country. It’s usually never possible to do a 1 to 1 translation between languages, but thank you again. I guess I got the idea from the very slangish sentence in Portuguese “Se você vier para o Brasil, a gente pode dar um role” which IMO is a total valid sentence, despite being heavily slang based though.

Comment: Tudo bem, "Se você vier ao Brasil, a gente pode dar um role" =If you come to Brazil, I can take you around. Take you around, not show you around. Em todo caso, seria melhor dizer uma cidade, né?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo problema com as suas sugestões. Também poderia usar "eu te mostro o lugar".

Comment: Eu te mostro o lugar(Brasil) acho que soa melhor, ao menos aos meus ouvidos haha obrigado

Comment: Sim, o inglês não funciona, porque: you can't  show a person around a country; you show a person around [a city or place]. Eu te levo a conhecer [o lugar]. Mas no caso, o Brasil ficaria um pouco exagerado....O Brasil aqui não pode ser "lugar" em inglês nem português.

Answer (score 2):

Em Português europeu diríamos

```
eu mostro-te as redondezas
```

O dicionário da Porto Editora tem esta entrada para o verbete [redondeza](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/redondezas).

> *plural* localidades próximas; **proximidades**; subúrbios

De referir ainda que, etimológica e morfologicamente, parece-me que redondezas (de redondo) se aplica melhor como vocábulo para traduzir "a-round".

Comment: Se for comparado ao francês, parece que se fala de outra coisa....

Comment: Mas em Português europeu, tal como consta em qualquer dicionário, a palavra redondezas no contexto espacial, significa isso mesmo, ou seja, "around". A palavra arredores tem uma interpretação mais próxima de "subúrbios". "Os arredores de Lisboa" por exemplo.

Comment: Eu sei, foi um piadinha. Em todo caso, não se aplicaria a um país inteiro.

Comment: Concordo contigo, João. Creio que no Brasil é a mesma coisa, que [*arredores* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/arredores) é o que está à volta, mas não incluindo o centro.

Comment: @Jacinto de referir ainda que etimológica e morfologicamente, parece-me que `redondezas` (de redondo) se aplica melhor como vocábulo para traduzir `a-round`.

Comment: @Lambie por curiosidade, pode especificar a que se refere? Não estou a ver nenhum vocábulo em francês similar com um significado pernicioso.

Comment: Não é exatamente a mesma palavra. Mas tem a ver:  Les rondeurs d'une femme. :) Como falo francês, me pareceu engraçado nesse sentido. Quem está falando do significado pernicioso? :)

Comment: @Lambie ah, `les rondeurs` conheço bem :) mas foneticamente diferente de redondezas. Em pt-PT diríamos `curvas`.

Answer (score 2):

to show someone around: levar alguém a visitar, vide abaixo.

Levar você a visitar a cidade, levar você a conhecer a cidade.

Coloquei cidade porque não seria o país inteiro.

You generally show someone around a city or place, not an entire country.

- servir de guia
- acompanhar alguém quando vem de visita/turista
- levar uma pessoa a visitar o conhecer  um lugar

Se você vier ao Rio, levo você a passear.

Passear para uma pessoa que não conhece um lugar poderia ser show you around.

Comment: Tu ofereces a melhor explicação de "show [someone] around"; mas a pergunta pede a tradução de uma frase, e as tuas duas últimas alternativas explicam bem, mas não as podemos simplesmente pôr na frase traduzida.

Comment: Posso levar você a visitar o Rio. You can't show someone around a country. Se você vier ao Rio, levo você a conhecer a cidade. Porque vocês não se dão conta de que  "show someone around a country" makes no sense?? It has to be: If you come to Rio, I'll show you around.

Comment: De acordo, mas o que eu sugiro é que traduzas essa frase mais sensata -- "if you come to Rio...".

Comment: Pois é, Jacinto: Si você vier ao Rio, levo você a passear.